# finding the correct path to "id" in this array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the Mavenlink API to create a project:

```
$response = $client->createWorkspace(array("title" => $project_number . ' ' . $company_name, "creator_role" => "maven"));

print_r($response);

$project_id = $response->id;

echo "project id: " . $project_id;
```

The part of creating the project is working fine, but I'm having trouble finding the correct path to "id". I want the ID so I can then use the update method to add more information to the project.

Heres a screenshot of the response output:

[image]

Raw response:

```
{"count":1,"workspaces":{"12220207":{"title":"34343 Add New","archived":false,"description":"","due_date":"","effective_due_date":"","start_date":"","budgeted":true,"change_orders_enabled":true,"updated_at":"2016-05-12T10:51:01-07:00","created_at":"2016-05-12T10:51:01-07:00","consultant_role_name":"FUEL","client_role_name":"Clients","percentage_complete":0,"access_level":"open","exclude_archived_stories_percent_complete":false,"can_create_line_items":true,"default_rate":"125.00","currency_symbol":"$","currency_base_unit":100,"can_invite":true,"has_budget_access":true,"tasks_default_non_billable":false,"rate_card_id":null,"workspace_invoice_preference_id":null,"posts_require_privacy_decision":false,"require_time_approvals":false,"require_expense_approvals":false,"stories_are_fixed_fee_by_default":false,"price":"TBD","price_in_cents":null,"budget_used":"$0","over_budget":false,"currency":"USD","expenses_in_burn_rate":true,"budget_used_in_cents":0,"total_expenses_in_cents":0,"status":{"color":"grey","message":"Not Started","key":130},"permissions":{"can_upload_files":true,"can_private_message":true,"can_join":false,"is_participant":true,"access_level":"admin","team_lead":true,"user_is_client":false},"creator_id":"10340340030","id":"12220207"}},"results":[{"key":"workspaces","id":"12220207"}]}
```

When I echo project_id, it is displaying blank. What is the correct path to target "id" ?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please post `$response` in the question.

Comment: Its shown in the screenshot

Comment: need raw, please post.

Comment: and one more thing, you need to decode the json for getting the `id`

Comment: added raw response

Comment: which id? creator_id or plain id beside it?

Comment: just the plain id beside it

Comment: in both answers please remove this piece of code `echo $arr->workspaces->{12220207}->id; //12220207` the number 12220207 is the one you are searching for. It is the id. If i already know it why should i use that command at all to search for it??? I would simply write `$project_id=12220207`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just json decode and you will get it. Let say you have `$json` your json.

[Online check](https://3v4l.org/WSpNf)

```
$arr = json_decode($json);    
echo $arr->workspaces->{12220207}->id; //12220207
```

For getting the results `id`

```
echo $arr->results[0]->id; //12220207
```

Comment: Im confused.. in the code you provided you are still supplying the id? that is what I dont know and am trying to extract

Comment: please check the online check. You have that id in your `json` as a key.

Comment: Awesome.. didnt see your edit! Thanks! Works great!

Comment: @cpcdev, never forgot to mark this as useful.

Comment: in your first example you use the value that you are searching for. `echo $arr->workspaces->{12220207}->id; //12220207` how someone is supposed to know the id that he is searching, since that might change?

Comment: Did you see the decode of the `json` string??? First check the array and then let me know what i did?

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode the json first using json_decode.

```
$response = json_decode($raw);
```

You could print it out so you can see the layout using print_r.

```
print_r($response);
```

As you can see it makes it an object, so you can easily access the information. The ID is the same under both results and inside workspaces. Therefore you have 2 solutions.

Either

```
$id = $response->results[0]->id;
```

Or

```
$id = $response->workspaces->{12220207}->id;
```

Which is obviously worse since the 12220207 is not a static number.

Comment: 12220207 is the id that is being searched so basically `$response->workspaces->{12220207}->id;` will return 12220207.

Comment: @PeterDarmis, from where you got this information that OP search with `12220207`?

Comment: @PeterDarmis so next time, he changes his parameters (the title and creator role) and he'll more than likely get a different workspace, with a different ID. He's not searching for that ID, he's getting it as a response. Pretty silly downvote.

Comment: i simply post the question... `title - > finding the correct path to “id” in this array`. I am using the Mavenlink API to create a project... The part of creating the project is working fine, but I'm having trouble finding the correct path to "id". I want the ID so I can then use the update method to add more information to the project.... When I echo project_id, it is displaying blank. What is the correct path to target "id" ? Thanks! Can you please read? @GunniH

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '{"count":1,"workspaces":{"12220207":{"title":"34343 Add New","archived":false,"description":"","due_date":"","effective_due_date":"","start_date":"","budgeted":true,"change_orders_enabled":true,"updated_at":"2016-05-12T10:51:01-07:00","created_at":"2016-05-12T10:51:01-07:00","consultant_role_name":"FUEL","client_role_name":"Clients","percentage_complete":0,"access_level":"open","exclude_archived_stories_percent_complete":false,"can_create_line_items":true,"default_rate":"125.00","currency_symbol":"$","currency_base_unit":100,"can_invite":true,"has_budget_access":true,"tasks_default_non_billable":false,"rate_card_id":null,"workspace_invoice_preference_id":null,"posts_require_privacy_decision":false,"require_time_approvals":false,"require_expense_approvals":false,"stories_are_fixed_fee_by_default":false,"price":"TBD","price_in_cents":null,"budget_used":"$0","over_budget":false,"currency":"USD","expenses_in_burn_rate":true,"budget_used_in_cents":0,"total_expenses_in_cents":0,"status":{"color":"grey","message":"Not Started","key":130},"permissions":{"can_upload_files":true,"can_private_message":true,"can_join":false,"is_participant":true,"access_level":"admin","team_lead":true,"user_is_client":false},"creator_id":"6333747","id":"12220207"}},"results":[{"key":"workspaces","id":"12220207"}]}';
$result = json_decode($json,true);    
//print_r($result);
echo $result['results'][0]['id'];
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/27d4ff8d1632177db97f9e9122e7a51bd6e11146